# Simple OpenCV Program crashes

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I am currently having a problem. I am following the instructions given in this book "OpenCV 2 Computer Vision Application Programming Cookbook" for creating a simple image display program in OpenCV (2.4.10-1) using Qt(5.4), QtCreator in Ubuntu 14.04.

The code is as follows:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // read an image
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("${PATH_TO_HOME}/Pictures/bottle_label.jpg");

    if ( image.data == NULL )    {
        std::cout << "no data loaded" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        // create image window named "My image"
        cv::namedWindow("My Image", 1);
        // show the image on window
        std::cout << "Image loaded" << std::endl;
        cv::imshow("My Image", image);
        // wait key for 5000 ms
        cv::waitKey(5000);

        return 0;
    } }
```

And the contents in the .pro file are

```
# Standard .pro content for qt console application #
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/

LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib \
        -lopencv_core  -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d
```

The code compiles, but when I run it the program crashes immediately. The debugger points a SIGSEGV occurring in line 17: cv::namedWindow("My Image", 1) I don't know what to do. I have other programs that use qt and opencv libraries in the same computer but used cmake (qt4 macros) to build them and they run fine. 
I have also wrote another similar test program using CMake and the new qt5 macros in the CMakeList.txt file. 
The program has a MainWindow with two buttons: The first opens an Image selected from a FileOpenDialog and the second Flips the image. Both images should be display using the cv::imshow() function. Again the program compiles, when I run it it crashes immediately. The debugger does not points to a particular line in my code.
The output in the console is:

```
*** Error in `${PATH_TO_EXEC_FILE}/myGUIApp': realloc(): invalid pointer: 0x00007ffff6d840e0 ***
```

The same console output is delivered with the above mentioned the code. Could someone please point out where the problem is?

Thank you in advance